# Calling a function and pass it a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json object named data like below

[image]

And I have a function denomination in a string like below

[image]

test is the name of the function I would like to call and pass it the json object data.

here is the test function:

```
test = function (data) {
    alert('I am the test function');
}
```

I already try:

```
eval(func(data));
```

It doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the function `test` defined?

Comment: Ok I updated my question to add the test function

Comment: [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). Either `data` is a string containing JSON, then you have to parse it first, or it is a JavaScript object/array.

Comment: What I actually meant was *where* it is defined. If it's a local variable, you won't have much luck finding a good option. If it's in the global scope, you can use `window[func]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While `eval()` is one possible solution, it is AWFUL.

Instead, interrogate the `window` to find the function you want and run it from there:

```
function test() {
    alert("test")       
}

var func = $("#confirm-remove").data("success");
var data = {}; // Your object
var fn = window[func];
if (typeof fn === 'function') {
    fn(data);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pSNWx/1/)

This assumes your function has global scope.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your test function is in the window scope, use this success function:

```
success: function (data) {
    var func = $('#confirm-remove').data('success');

    window[func](data);                        
}
```